# Bibtex saying empty bibliography when it is not empty

Tags: latex, bibliography, overleaf

So I am trying to print my bibliography on my LaTex file and am having trouble. The package I am using is

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, sorting=ynt]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}
```

At the end of my document (still inside the document section though), I use `\printbibliography` and am being told "Empty bibliography on line 53" (that is the line that the `\printbibliography` is on). Inside of my bibliography I have this:

```
@article{junger1995traveling,
    title={The traveling salesman problem},
    author={J{\"u}nger, Michael and Reinelt, Gerhard and Rinaldi, Giovanni},
    journal={Handbooks in operations research and management science},
    volume={7},
    pages={225--330},
    year={1995},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

Any ideas why my bibliography is not showing? I am using Overleaf btw.

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]. Are you actually citing anything within your document?

Comment: Have you used `\cite` or `\nocite` in the document? If you don't call those two commands, biber will not add entries to the bibliography so it tells you it is empty.